# Getting the SqlCommand Type from Generic T in .net

Tags: function, generics, c#-2.0

i have created a generic function named `ExecuteProcedure<T>(T command, string parameters)`, now inside the `ExecuteProcedure` function i want to cast the `T into SqlCommand`, so that i can use `SqlCommand's` properties like `Parameters.Add()` here is my code.

```
T could be SqlCommand or SqlDataAdapter
```

here's my code:

```
public void ExecuteProcedure<T>(T command, string parameters)
{
    using (connection)
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(SqlCommand))
        {
           //how to convert into SqlCommand Here to use command.CommandType Property below.
        }
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        foreach (string param in parameters.Split(','))
        {
            SqlParameter par = new SqlParameter(param, param.Substring(1, param.Length - 1));
            command.Parameters.Add(par);
        }


        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to CAST T to SqlCommand

```
SqlCommand cmd = (SqlCommand)Convert.ChangeType(command, typeof(SqlCommand));
```

anyways thanks @Chris

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you have to do is:

```
SqlCommand cmd = (SqlCommand)(object)command;
```

Comment: hi @Chris, i tried that, but its not working, it throws compile time error, saying cannot convert type T to System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

Comment: Ahh, yes, no constraint.  Try casting to 'object' then to the known type.  Answer updated.